# How can I increase memory_limit for batch processes only?

Tags: .htaccess, batch-operations

I have a batch process that occasionally exceeds the memory_limit, which is currently 96M. Of course I know the [ways to increase the memory limit](http://drupal.org/node/207036) for the whole site, but I prefer to increase the memory limit for batch pages only.

One way I could think of, is to implement [hook_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) in a custom module and do `ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');` whenever `arg(0) == 'batch'`, but I'm not sure if that is the best solution.

What do you recommend? I guess I could do it in .htaccess, but regex isn't exactly my forte...

[update]
Meanwhile, more searching tells me ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957600/make-php-value-conditional-in-htaccess), [Webmasterworld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/381.htm)) that it is not possible to add a conditional php_value directive to .htaccess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that @kantu's answer is the proper thing to do, but I am going to offer up an alternate solution that is a little hackish.

If you don't want to do a module, then you could add the setting to `settings.php` wrapped in a conditional.  Just note that this is included really early in the bootstrap process, so you don't have access to the vast majority of the API.

You could try adding

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/batch") === 0) {
  ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');
}
```

to the file.

I would also double check the PHP doc about [`memory_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) (or post a question on one of the sister sites).  I believe that PHP doesn't allocate this during startup; it is just a safety limit to prevent imploding your server.  I am pretty sure you can just bump up this limit globally.

If you are worried about Apache hanging on to this memory, then you can play with the [`MaxMemFree`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxmemfree) setting for Apache.  A while ago, I did a site that would need huge amounts of memory very infrequently.  Tweaking this parameter, along with a [`MaxRequestsPerChild`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild), kept my server running happily.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about MaxMemFree yet. AFAIK, you're right about memory_limit: PHP will only use the memory it needs.

Comment: I realize this is an old question / answer... but I was searching again for the proper way to do this. Acquia recommends this method of using the settings.php file.
https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004542293-Conditionally-increasing-memory-limits

Answer (score 6):

I had similar requirement , but for admin/build/modules pages as it consumed more memory

```
function memory_setup_init() {
 //Check for pages goes here
  if (...) {
    ini_set('memory_limit', $memory_limit .'M');
  }
}
```

My modules pages required 150MB sometimes as it was heavily loaded.
I suggest this approach as you can set up a form and you will have ability to turn it on/off or increase on the fly.Hope this gives you some idea to continue.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the solution I referred to in my question. I'm sure it would work, but my gut feeling tells me that a custom module (even this small) is overkill for modifying a single php setting.

Comment: For my case it was required to be a separate module as I had one separate Form (system_settings_form) where I could group some pages and set memory for it, else you can make use of any existing modules.